# How do I populate TextBox fields from a ComboBox selection?

Tags: c#, sql-server, combobox, textbox

I am in the process of building a Drone Pilot logbook. In the logbook, on the Pilots page, you select from a `comboBox` at the top to choose your pilot. This data is taken from a SQL Server (`.MDF`) database file in the project.  Once you have chosen the pilot, existing data from the database populates the rest of the form. The code I have below queries the SQL Server database file successfully and shows the `FullName` in the `comboBox`, but now I'm at a blank as far as how I get the rest of the form to fill out (i.e. `FirstName`, `LastName`, `Address`, `City`, etc.)

```
private void frmPilots_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Kevin\ownCloud\Programming\C# Projects\DroneLogbook\DroneLogbook\data.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30"))
    {
        SqlCommand sc = new SqlCommand("select Id,FullName from Pilots", conn);
        conn.Open();

        SqlDataReader reader;
        reader = sc.ExecuteReader();

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("FullName", typeof(string));

        dt.Load(reader);

        cmbExistingPilot.ValueMember = "Id";
        cmbExistingPilot.DisplayMember = "FullName";
        cmbExistingPilot.DataSource = dt;

        conn.Close();
    }
```

Comment: If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the gray check mark beside the answer. Check this link to know How does accepting an answer work: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1):

You need another `select` statement based on the selected value of your `ComboBox` and a [`SqlDataReader`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader(v=vs.110).aspx) to fill out your `TextBoxes`. Something like this:

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(
      "SELECT FirstName, LastName FROM Pilots where Id = @Id;",
      connection);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id",cmbExistingPilot.SelectedValue.ToString());
connection.Open();

SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

if (reader.HasRows)
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        txtFirstName.Text = reader.GetString(0);
        txtLastName.Text = reader.GetString(1);
        //and...
    }
}
```